# ReactJS with Typescript template useContext property does not exists on type {}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I created a react-app using `yarn create react-app app-name --template typescript`, here is my code

AuthProvider.tsx

```
    import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext({ });
export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState({});
  
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, setAuth }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthContext;
```

Login.tsx

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import AuthContext from "./context/AuthProvider";
const Login = () => {
  const { setAuth } = useContext(AuthContext);
  /*codes here*/
  return <></>;
};

export default Login;
```

The error is `Property 'setAuth' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)`, but when I change the file extension to `.js` it's not showing error. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define type of `AuthContext`:

```
interface Auth {
  // properties of auth object you're using in const [auth, setAuth] = useState({});
};
const AuthContext = createContext<{ auth?: Auth, setAuth?: (auth: Auth) => void }>({ });
```

Adjust `Auth` and context type as needed to match your requirements.

Without passing a type to `useContext`, typescript infers it from the initial value passed to the hook, which is `{}`, and has none of the properties you're passing to it later in the provider.